# how to convert framework 4 to 3.5

Tags: .net

I have built a project using 4.0 , how can I convert it to 3.5?

Comment: Change it in the Project-Settings?

Comment: Are you asking how to "back port" all the code to 3.5 or jest change the projec settings to compile wiht 3.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your developing using Visual studio? For VB.Net, goto project properties -> Compile tab -> press the Advanced compile options button and you can then select the target framework (should be similar for c# projects).

There are not alot of "major" language changes between 3.5 and 4.0 so you should be able to re-compile in 3.5, however this will depend.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd409230(VS.100).aspx for a complete list of changes in 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project properties, choose the 'application' tab, and change the target framework setting.